# Find the normal probability $P(|X|<1)$ using z values?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

If I have a random variable that follows a normal distribution i.e.
$X \sim N(-3,4)$ 
and I want to calculate $P(|X| <1)$ how would I go about doing so, using the z values? Seeing as it's the modulus, would I only need to consider one half of the normal curve and thus calculate $P(X<1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember the definition of the absolute value: $|X|<1$ means that the distance from $X$ to the origin is less than 1. Hence, if $|X|<1$, which one of the following alternatives is true?

a) $X > 0$.

b) $-1<X<1$.

c) $10^{100}<X<10^{100^{100}}$.

d) None of the above.

Now, the probability that $X$ is between two values $a$ and $b$, with $a<b$, is the area below the graph of the density of $X$ between $a$ and $b$. It is a good idea to draw a figure that depicts this area. One way to compute that area is to subtract two other areas: the area below the graph of the density of $X$ from $-\infty$ to $b$, minus the area below the graph of the density of $X$ from $-\infty$ to $a$. Make sure that you understand why this is true: draw another figure. Finally, the two areas mentioned above can be obtained, in your case, from the $z$-values, right?

Answer (score 4):

No, $P(X<1)$ is different from $P(|X|<1)$. After all  $-2 < 1$ but $|-2|$ isn't!

To get  $P(|X|<1)$ you need to find this area:

[image: required area]

. . .

While $P(X<1)$ would be this area:

[image: wrong area]

[Credit: I used the `shadenorm` function [here](https://gist.github.com/tony91782/950812), which was written by [Tony Cookson](http://novicemetrics.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/how-to-shade-under-normal-density-in-r.html). To editorialize a little, one mark of a really good utility function is one for which basic usage can be discerned from simply reading the argument list; this was one of those - paste it in, use it in the obvious way, it worked. It looks like there's a similar function [`shade.norm`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/asbio/docs/shade.norm) in the package `asbio` (see the description [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/asbio/docs/shade.norm))]

Comment: And if I wanted to calculate $P(|X|>1)$ could I do: 1 - P(-1<X<1)?

Comment: Correct (though strictly you're leaving out some equalities at the bounds, they have probability of measure zero so teh answer won't change) - but you should probably add that question to your original post

Answer (score 3):

In R this should work.

```
X <- rnorm(100000,-3,4)
X1<- abs(x)
mean(X1<1)
.14854
```

This creates 100,000 random normal variables with mean -3 and sd= 4.  (R uses sd as the second parameter.  Make sure you use 2 if you mean variance of 4 in your example).  The second line of code just takes the absolute value of the variables, then line three just checks for percentage less than 1.

R has a function (`pnorm`) which is the cumulative density function for the normal distribution (it also exists for many other distributions other than the normal).  `pnorm` basically says what portion of the pdf is less than or equal to a certain number.  For your example, you're looking for numbers between -1 and 1 (i.e. absolute value of 1), so `pnorm(1,-3,4)` will tell you $P(x<1)$.  Now that will give you more than you want, because you don't want numbers smaller than $(x<-1)$.  So you've got to cut out that portion of the distribution.

Writing the code `pnorm(1,mean=-3,sd=4) - pnorm(-1,mean=-3, sd=4)` should then give you the portion of the distribution to the left of the value $1$, but to the right of the value $-1$.  I got an answer of `.14998` when I ran this code.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you explain why you are advocating such an approach over using, e.g., the built-in `R` functions such as `pnorm`? It also seems unclear whether a programming solution is what the OP is searching for over, say, an explicit expression.

Comment: pnorm(1,mean=-3,sd=4)-pnorm(-1,mean=-3,4)

Comment: I think that this works too.  You are right, this is better. Sorry.

Comment: No reason to be sorry. I was fishing for more elaboration. One can gain insight and understanding through such simulations. You might consider an edit that incorporates your comment and also shows *why* it works. I've found in the past that a carefully constructed picture can remove all doubt from even the most mathphobic. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I was wondering if I could get a more theoretical answer? What probability are you actually calculating with |X|?