# How to calculate a p-value without using a lookup table

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I'm looking for the formula to calculate a p-value for statistical hypothesis testing by hand without using the lookup table. I've found something here ([Calculating P-Value of a Z-Score without using Z-Table](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425561/calculating-p-value-of-a-z-score-without-using-z-table)), but I don't really understand the formula. Can someone help me by showing some data and how you come up with a p-value based on that data. So, simply filling in the formula. For a Z-test, T-test or what is feasible. Would be much appreciated!

Comment: In general, this will involve an integral with typically no closed form, so you need to do numerical integration. You could also use built-in commands of standard statistical tools like R or Pythong - which again rely internally on tables. In some cases, e.g., in a permutation or bootstrap test, it would be a matter of evaluating the empirical cumulative distribution function - which is nothing else than counting outcomes. Can you be more precise as to what test you are interested in, and on why you don't want to use a table?

Comment: The duplicate has an extensive (and very good) discussion of various ways to do this calculation "by hand."  When I'm in the field and need to do such a calculation I find that Simpson's Rule (consult your favorite Calculus textbook) works quite well.

Comment: Yes, I recognized the integral part in the formula, but have difficulty with applying it to data. The reason I'm interested in the calculation of the p-value is to get a deeper understanding of how statistical testing works. In the past, I used Excel and R to get p-values, but now I want to try to calculate it manually in Excel. The type of test doesn't really matter, let's say to use the Z-test. Could you provide an example how the formula is used, including the numerical integration?

Comment: We have a great many [tag:self-study] questions here on CV that perform this calculation (probably several thousands by now).  Although it's difficult to suggest a search term, I'm pretty sure a review of these textbook questions will quickly turn up some good examples.  Here's a [refined search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bself-study%5D+normal+probability+answers%3A1) that has some promising hits on the first page of its results.  It found the illustrated answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52545/919, for instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, whuber. I'll dive deeper in the sources you suggest.